# Codeigniter Proper Way to Loop Joins with Multiple Results?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I will give a small example to explain what i mean.

```
CREATE TABLE blog
(
 b_id int primary key not null,
  b_title varchar(255) not null,
  b_body text not null,
  CONSTRAINT pk_b_id_01 PRIMARY KEY(b_id)
 )

 CREATE TABLE images
 (
  i_id int primary key not null,
  i_image varchar(255) not null,
  i_b_id int not null,
  CONSTRAINT pk_i_id_01 PRIMARY KEY(i_id)
 )
```

lets say in an admin area i wanna show a table with each subject of the blog and all the images assigned to it whether it has 1 image or 5 images.

currently i do it like this

```
$query = $this->db->get("blog");
foreach($query->result() as $qr)
{
    echo $qr->b_title . "<br />";
    $query2 = $this->db->get_where("images", array('i_b_id'=>$qr->b_id));
    foreach($query2->result() as $qr2)
    {
        echo $qr2->i_image . "<br />";
    }
    echo "<hr />\n";
}
```

My question is there a way to do this with 1 query instead of potentially 30 or however many posts there are?

i tried to do this with a join but its only showing the first image.

```
$this->db->join("images", "i_b_id = b_id");
$query = $this->db->get("blog");
foreach($query->result() as $qr)
{
    echo $qr->b_title . "<br />";
    $query2 = $this->db->get_where("images", array('i_b_id'=>$qr->b_id));

    //is there another for loop i can do here?
    echo $qr->i_image . "<br />";

    echo "<hr />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a join should result in duplicate blog data for each image. To avoid showing the same title over and over, just use some simple logic:

```
$current_blog_id = -1;
foreach($query->result() as $qr)
{
    // only output the title if it's a new blog
    if ($qr->b_id != $current_blog_id)
    {
        if ($current_blog_id != -1) echo "<hr />\n";

        echo $qr->b_title . "<br />";

        $current_blog_id = $qr->b_id;
    }

    echo $qr->i_image . "<br />";
}
```